# coker isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $H$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-module presented by the matrix $A \in Mat_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{Z})$ (i.e. $H = coker A$). Let $R$ and $L$ be two invertible matrices such that
$C= L \cdot A \cdot R$ is a diagonal matrix and let $H'$ be the $\mathbb{Z}$-module presented by $C$. Clearly, $H$ is isomorphic to $H'$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

> How do we write the isomorphism $H \to H'$ explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a category $\mathcal C$, the *arrow category of $\mathcal C$* is the category $\mathcal C^\to$ whose objects are morphisms of $\mathcal C$, and a morphism from $f \colon A \to B$ to $f’ \colon A’ \to B’$ is a pair $(a,b)$ of morphisms $a \colon A \to A’$ and $b \colon B \to B’$ that makes commutative the following diagram. The composition in $\mathcal C^\to$ is performed entrywise.
$$
\newcommand{\coker}{\operatorname{coker}}
\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{a}>> A’ \\
@V{f}VV @VV{f’}V \\
B @>>{b}> B’
\end{CD}
$$
Note that a morphism $(a,b)$ in $\mathcal C^\to$ is an isomorphism if and only if $a$ and $b$ are isomorphisms.

Now, let $R$ be a ring, and consider the category $R\textsf{-Mod}$ of left $R$-modules. We claim that the map $f \mapsto \coker f$ is the object map of a functor
$$
\coker \colon (R\textsf{-Mod})^\to \to R\textsf{-Mod}
$$
Indeed, if $(a,b)$ is a morphism from $f \colon A \to B$ to $f’ \colon A’ \to B’$, then
$$
b[\im f] = b[f[A]] = f’[a[A]] \subseteq f’[A’] = \im f’
$$
and so the map $\coker{(a,b)} \colon \coker f \to \coker f’$ that sends $x+\im f$ to $b(x)+\im f’$ is well-defined.

As a corollary, the fact that any functor preserves isomorphisms implies that if $(a,b)$ is an isomorphism, then so is $\coker{(a,b)}$.

In your case, the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Z^3 @>{R^{-1}}>> \Z^3 \\
@V{A}VV @VV{C}V \\
\Z^3 @>>{L}> \Z^3
\end{CD}
$$
commutes by definition of $C$, so $(R^{-1},L)$ is an isomorphism from $A$ to $C$, and therefore $\coker{(R^{-1},L)}$ is an isomorphism from $\coker A$ to $\coker C$.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer. The map $coker(a,b)$ gives the explicit map we were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have $H = \mathbb{Z}^3 / A \mathbb{Z}^3$ and $H' = \mathbb{Z}^3/C \mathbb{Z}^3$. Note that $A \mathbb{Z}^3 = AR \mathbb{Z}^3$ since $R$ is invertible. The matrix $L$ induces an invertible map $\mathbb{Z}^3 \to \mathbb{Z}^3$ mapping $A \mathbb{Z}^3 = AR \mathbb{Z}^3$ to $LAR \mathbb{Z}^3 = C \mathbb{Z}^3$ and thus inducing the desired isomorphism $H \to H'$.